# ElementName binding cannot find the source while RelativeSource binding works just fine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following object structure:

```
Window (not relevant)
   SearchView (name: ucSearchView, DataContext: SearchViewModel)
      SearchComboBox (name: ucSearchComboBox, DataContext: inherited SearchViewModel)
```

and then inside `SearchComboBox.xaml` there is:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"> <!-- SearchResults is a list of strings -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding}" <-- DataContext is a string at this point -->
                    Background="{Binding Ugabuga, ElementName=ucSearchView}" /> <!-- The binding that cannot find the ucSearchView -->
           </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Binding examples below. **Ugabuga is a property that does not exist on purpose. It's all about finding the source object.**

---

{Binding Ugabuga, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
> 'Ugabuga' property not found on 'object' ''SearchComboBox'
> (Name='**ucSearchComboBox**')'. BindingExpression:Path=Ugabuga;
> DataItem='SearchComboBox' (Name='ucSearchComboBox'); target element is
> 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

{Binding Ugabuga, ElementName=**ucSearchComboBox**}

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
> 'Ugabuga' property not found on 'object' ''SearchComboBox'
> (Name='**ucSearchComboBox**')'. BindingExpression:Path=Ugabuga;
> DataItem='SearchComboBox' (Name='ucSearchComboBox'); target element is
> 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

**Example above works fine. It finds the source object in both cases.**

---

{Binding Ugabuga, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, **AncestorLevel=2**}}

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
> 'Ugabuga' property not found on 'object' ''SearchView'
> (Name='**ucSearchView**')'. BindingExpression:Path=Ugabuga;
> DataItem='SearchView' (Name='ucSearchView'); target element is
> 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

{Binding Ugabuga, ElementName=**ucSearchView**}

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
> reference 'ElementName=ucSearchView'. BindingExpression:Path=Ugabuga;
> DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
> property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

**Question:** What happens here? Why does RelativeSource find the object named ucSearchView, but ElementName doesn't? Does it have anything to do with name scopes?

**NOTE:** My goal here is not to make the binding work. I just want to understand this behaviour.

Comment: Element name must reference a name that exists within the current namescope. A DataTemplate (as well as Style) has its own namescope. This is because a DataTemplate is usually loaded multiple times, for example once per item of an ItemsControl. If a DataTemplate had not its own namescope the names of the multiple times existing elements would cause a collision. But because DataTemplate/Style has its own namescope the element names contained within are again unique as per requirement.

Comment: [WPF XAML Namescopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: The RelativeSource extension on the other hand is scope independent. It simply traverses the element tree (logical tree). In your case it just iterates recursively over the parents until it finds the element declared by AncestorType and AncestorLevel.

Comment: @BionicCode. Thanks for a quick comment. That absolutely makes sense. I thought it might have something to do with the name scopes. Is there actually any list of elements that have their own namescopes or are not added to the visual/logical tree?

Comment: Usually the namescope is implicitly defined on the root element by the XAML engine, which is for example a Window, Page, Popup or UserControl, and as mentioned the DataTemplate and Style provide their own namescope. You can call NameScope.SetNameScope (the setter of the attached property NameScope.NameScope) to explicitly create a new namescope.

Comment: @BionicCode. Actually, I have another place in the project with a ScrollViewer that uses DataTemplate and I am able to bind using ElementName there. Weird. Moreover, in the example above you can see that binding by ElementName finds ucSearchCombobox which is also "above" DataTemplate and thus should be outside of the namescope, no?

Comment: There are special cases that could prevent the engine to resolve the element. The engine is able traverse the logical tree towards the root to find the next namescope.  Obviously the namescope of ucSearchView is out of reach.

Comment: Just a side note. When you wrap the ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer you are essentially scrolling the complete control. But you want to scroll the items inside the ItemsControl. That's why you must put the ItemsPresenter into the ScrollViewer instead. Now you can set e.g. Height on the ItemsControl. ListBox is an advanced ItemsControl in that it provides a ScrollViewer by default and additional performance features like UI virtualization as well as access to the selected item via event and properties (ListBox extends Selector). You should always prefer ListBox over ItemsControl.

Comment: You should prefer postbox over itemscontrol IF you want to scroll items and or select an item. If you don't then an itemscontrol is simpler and likely preferable.

Comment: Damn... Auto flipping correct. Should obviously say listbox rather than postbox.